# Getting Xpatch for importxml google sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was tying to get info from this website call  Maple.gg.

Using this

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://maple.gg/u/",C1) ,"//*[@id=""character-card""]/div/ul[1]/li[3]/span")
```

Its not working anymore;(
So I was truing `tk` get `xpatch` of it, but I don't get something like `@id`, but I'm getting this instead.

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[1]/img
```

How can I get something like @id for `xpatch`>

Copy `xpath` won't work or not give me URL I need.

Comment: You have tagged `excel` AND `google-sheets`. Please choose one or the other - you can't choose both.